# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.datetime' and 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.9

I am trying to build a network monitor using python that continually monitors internet connectivity by sending ping requests to an external resource. It also keeps logs of when the internet is down and the duration of the downtime. While running this python program, I am getting the error.

```
    import socket
    import time
    import datetime
    import os
    import sys
        
    LOG_FNAME = "network.log"
    FILE = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), LOG_FNAME)
    def send_ping_request(host="1.1.1.1", port=53, timeout=3):
        try:
            socket.setdefaulttimeout(timeout)
            s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            s.connect((host,port))
        except OSError as error:
            return False
        else:
            s.close()
            return True
    def write_permission_check():
        try:
            with open(FILE, "a") as file:
                pass
        except OSError as error:
            print("Log file creation failed")
            sys.exit()
        finally:
            pass

    def calculate_time(start, stop):
        time_difference = stop - start
        seconds = float(str(time_difference.total_seconds()))
        return str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=seconds)).split(".")[0]
    def mon_net_connection(ping_freq=2):
        monitor_start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    def motd():
        motd = "Network connection monitoring started at: " + 
    str(monitor_start_time).split(".")[0] + " Sending ping request in " + str(ping_freq) + " seconds"
        print(motd)

    with open(FILE, "a") as file:
        file.write("\n")
        file.write("motd" + "\n")
    while True:
        if send_ping_request():
            time.sleep(1)
        else:
            down_time = datetime.datetime.now()
            fail_msg = "Network Connection Unavailable at: " +str(down_time).split(".")[0]
            print(fail_msg)
            with open(FILE, "a") as file:
                file.write(fail_msg + "\n")
                i = 0
            while not send_ping_request():
                time.sleep(1)
                i += 1
                if i >= 3600:
                    i = 0
                    now = datetime.datetime.now()
                    continous_message = "Network Unavailabilty Persistent at: " +str(now).split(".")[0]
                    print(continous_message)
                    with open(FILE, "a") as file:
                        file.write(continous_message + "\n")
                up_time = datetime.datetime.now()
                uptime_message = "Network Connectivity Restored at: " +str(up_time).split(".")[0]
 
                down_time = calculate_time(down_time, up_time)
                _m = "Network Connection was Unavailable for " + down_time
 
                print(uptime_message)
                print(_m)
 
                with open(FILE, "a") as file:
                    file.write(uptime_message + "\n")
                    file.write(_m + "\n")
        mon_net_connection()
```

The error I am getting is as below.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\samsung\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\checknetwork1.py", line 
    64, in <module>
        down_time = calculate_time(down_time, up_time)
      File "C:\Users\samsung\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\checknetwork1.py", line 29, in calculate_time
        time_difference = stop - start
    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.datetime' and 'str'
```

Please help in resolving this error. I am unable to figure out where is the error, and how to correct it.

Comment: `down_time = calculate_time(down_time, up_time)` — `calculate_time` returns a string. Which you're assigning to `down_time`. And then in a subsequent loop iteration you pass back into `calculate_time`…

Answer (score 0):

The `down_time` variable is initially set to type `datetime.datetime` as is the `up_time` variable. The problem is in your `while` loop, the first call to `calculate_time()` returns a `str` which gets assigned to `down_time`, so the next time you call it in the loop, the type will not work.

I'm not entirely sure what the loop is trying to accomplish but if you want to maintain this pattern, you need `calculate_time` to return a `datetime.datetime` object and explicitly cast it to `str` when you need to print or log it.